# TFS Banching from a VS project Label

Tags: tfs, branch

I have a TFS branch Main. I want to create a hotfix branch for MVCWebSite project.

My build definition for MVCWebSite applied a Label to MVCWebSite and the SharedClassLibrary only, I wasn't releasing the ConsoleApps so didn't need a Label for these.

```
\MvcMusicStore\Main\MySolution\ConsoleApp1
\MvcMusicStore\Main\MySolution\ConsoleApp2
\MvcMusicStore\Main\MySolution\MVCWebSite
\MvcMusicStore\Main\MySolution\SharedClassLibrary
\MvcMusicStore\Main\MySolution\Packages
\MvcMusicStore\Main\MySolution\BuildProcessTemplates
```

How can I create a HotFix for just the MVCWebSite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not suggest making a branch only for the single project you need to branch the entire solution.  You can use the changeset number instead of the label to get the appropriate version of the entire solution and then convert that into a branch.  Steps:

- Find the label you want
- Open it and get the changeset number (screenshot below)
- Get specific version based on changeset number
- Convert to branch

[image]

Comment: Yep, I can see this working. Colin Dembovsky has a great article on how to do fixes without a branch. http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/branch-is-not-equal-to-environment. However what about a scenario where i need to fix code for say the website. I get that label etc but in creating the fix i also now need to create a fix in a related console app how would i get that code as its not built with the web and therfore got a different tfs label.

Comment: The website and console app could be in the same branch but different solutions if you like.  Then the same branch-level label would still apply.  If they must be in different branches you would need to manage their versions and labels separately.